# What did Obama mean when he said, "John was the stein of one of America's most distinguished military families."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am not sure I understand Barack Obama's use of the word **stein** in the [speech](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/read-full-transcript-barack-obama-161300166.html) he delivered at John McCain's funeral:

> And in fact on the surface, John and i could not have been more different. We're of different generations. I came from a broken home and never knew my father. John was the **stein** of one of America's most distinguished military families. I have a reputation for keeping cool, John not so much.

I have checked several dictionaries, and **stein** is a beer mug as I already know. But what does Obama mean here?

Comment: It's [*John was the **son** of one of America's most distinguished military families,*](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/09/01/politics/obama-mccain-eulogy/index.html)  as correctly reported by CNN in that link. You're citing an erroneous entry [as scraped from the Internet by Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stein) in an "example usage" for the unrelated word ***stein***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a meaningless mistranscription / typo.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm with sumelic on this and expect Obama used "scion", because he actually knew how to use words like that.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, now I've listened to the audio through sumelic's link, it's obvious he's saying ***scion***, not ***son***. But it's still an OffTopic question about a mistranscription, even if I happen to have cited a ***different*** mistranscription (by CNN) in my closevote text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the context, I'm certain that Obama used the word *[scion](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=scion),* not "stein". As the American Heritage Dictionary says, *scion* in this context means

> A descendant or heir, especially of a wealthy or prominent family: *scion of the ruling dynasty.*

You can listen to [Obama speaking here](https://youtu.be/raDyWogvQ2Y?t=230); I don't hear "stein" at all. I hear /sk/ at the start: the linked video mistranscribes it as "sky on".

Using /sk/ in this word is actually unconventional: the pronunciation found in the Oxford English dictionary is "/ˈsaɪən/" ("SIGH-un"). But there's an obvious explanation for why Obama might have pronounced *scion* with /sk/: the influence of the many other words spelled with *sc-* and pronounced with /sk/. A similar (possibly more common) pronunciation variant with /sk/ instead of /s/ exists for the word *proboscis.*

Obama's use of /sk/ in this instance may actually have just been a slip of the tongue: he seems to have used a /k/-less pronunciation of *scion* in his [eulogy for Beau Biden](https://youtu.be/lyAD8h1M4to?t=445) in 2015.